# Numpy matrix multiplication error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 2 big matrices:

```
       Xn = np.matrix(X)
       Xnt = Xn.transpose()
```

Then Xn is like this:

```
   >>> Xn
   matrix([['0,208', '0,22', '0,208', ..., '0,194', '0,205', '0,205'],
    ['0,22', '0,208', '0,214', ..., '0,205', '0,205', '0,214'],
    ['0,208', '0,214', '0,22', ..., '0,205', '0,214', '0,211'],
    ..., 
    ['0,214', '0,214', '0,208', ..., '0,199', '0,211', '0,226'],
    ['0,214', '0,208', '0,208', ..., '0,211', '0,226', '0,252'],
    ['0,208', '0,208', '0,211', ..., '0,226', '0,252', '0,24']], 
   dtype='|S5')
```

But I want to multiply Xn and Xnt. An error occurs.

```
  >>> print(Xn*Xnt)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(Xn*Xnt)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 330, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Your matrix elements are strings - note `dtype='|S5'` when you print the matrix. Try converting the elements of `X` from strings to floats first.

Comment: @mtrw close this one or re-formulate as an answer :-)

Comment: @146percentRussian, you should accept the answer provided by mtrw if it answered your question, which it looks like it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix elements are strings - note `dtype='|S5'` when you print the matrix. Try converting the elements of X from strings to floats first.