# Python Numpy.matrix multiplication error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I’m taking an online machine learning class through Cousera.  The class is taught in Matlab but I’m trying to learn Python so I’m trying to rewrite the assignments in Python after I have the Matlab stuff done.  I have the following code:

```
import numpy as n

X = n.matrix(dataX)
theta = n.zeros(shape=(2, 1))
predictions = n.matrix(X * theta)
```

X/dataX is a 97x2 matrix pulled in from a CSV.  Theta is a array 2x1 of zeros that I’m trying to multiply to X.  I should get 97x1 array of zeros to the output for predictions.  But I get the following error instead:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3 /Users/jsmith/Documents/python/Assign1/CostFunction.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jsmith/Documents/python/Assign1/CostFunction.py", line 24, in <module>
    predictions = n.matrix(X * theta)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 341, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I’ve also tried:

```
predictions = X * theta
```

And I get the same “ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize” error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `dataX` a string? or a list of lists?  Please show us (at least the beginning of) `repr(dataX)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is saying the item type is wrong... There's a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659308/numpy-matrix-multiplication-error)
If you have loaded it from a csv file, you may have ended up with strings.

e.g. if you used `csvreader` tell numpy the data is numeric:

```
x=list(reader)
result=numpy.array(x).astype('float')
```

Comment: Yup...  That was it.  The CSV was importing as something called "<u16" for a type.  Thanks!!